# Can I create a dialog box as seen in Blackberry using pure J2ME package

Tags: blackberry, java-me, dialog, alert, lcdui

I know we Alert is used as Pop up box in j2me but
can I create a pop up as good looking as dialog box of Blackberry using pure j2me packages?
Or I need to customize using Canvas class?

Is there a dialog box in j2me? if yes can I get an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, Just create one canvas with background image transparent and use another images for same like dialog box(images create from adobe Photoshop) , so this canvas you can use it anywhere in application. thanks

Comment: i did used Dialog d=new Dialog();

Answer (score 0):

use d.show();
show method is for showing dialog

Comment: But the use of Dialog d=new Dialog() is for lwuit ... not for pure j2me package