# How to use Dialog class in j2me

Tags: java-me, dialog, lwuit

I need to know how to use a Dialog class in J2me.

Any example.

I created a `Dialog d=new Dialog()` as per seen in one of the questions answered in Stack Overflow:

- [How can I show dialog box on canvas in J2ME mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664243/how-can-i-show-dialog-box-on-canvas-in-j2me-mobile-application)

But it gives an error Dialog() not visible.

I got `import gov.nist.siplite.stack.Dialog;` package for Dialog box

Comment: "one of the questions answered in Stack Overflow" - is this about [comment you made in an answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803880/can-i-create-a-dialog-box-as-seen-in-blackberry-using-pure-j2me-package#comment12486114_9804212)?

Comment: No ... i did found somewhere but i lost the link

Comment: Anyways do you got an example of Dialog() in j2me

Comment: what Dialog are you talking about? J2ME is too broad sorry, eg in MIDP LCDUI API, there's no such class `Dialog`. What API are you using? Blackberry, LWUIT, J2ME Polish, something else?

Comment: i am using Pure j2me class where i got import gov.nist.siplite.stack.Dialog; package for Dialog box

Comment: are you sure about this import? did you by chance somehow mistaken it with LWUIT Dialog, like one discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664243/how-can-i-show-dialog-box-on-canvas-in-j2me-mobile-application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong import that takes Dialog object from wrong project (details below) instead of LWUIT.

For more details on how to use LWUIT, refer to **['lwuit' tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lwuit/info)**.

---

> I got `import gov.nist.siplite.stack.Dialog;` package for Dialog box

Given above it looks like you are trying to work with *Sip-for-me project*.

<sub>Here is the reference to source code of `gov.nist.siplite.stack.Dialog` class at the project homepage:

- http://java.net/projects/sip-for-me/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/sip4me/gov/nist/siplite/stack/Dialog.java</sub>

---

> an example of Dialog()

You can look for usage examples at [Sip-for-me project homepage](http://java.net/projects/sip-for-me) or ask at their "Users mailing list" which is also referred to from project page.

As far as I can tell, project isn't particularly active and their documentation looks rather poor, so you may also consider following reference given at their [svn / trunk page](http://java.net/projects/sip-for-me/sources/svn/show/trunk):

```
    Contributions were made by many people to NIST-SIP. Please see 

    http://jain-sip.dev.java.net/
```